# How traversing from node to node is happened in a Linked list

Tags: java, linked-list

I just started to learn the concept of Linked List recently, and have a problem on how the else statement works in the below code. How does it traverse to next node until a NULL value is found in the node?

```
public class LinkedList {

Node head;

public void insert(int data) {
    Node node = new Node(data);
    node.data = data;

    if(head == null) {

        head = node;

    }else{

        Node temp = head;
        while(temp.next != null) {
            temp = temp.next;
        }
        temp.next = node;

      }
   }  
}
```

Comment: You can almost simply read that in english. `while(temp.next != null) temp = temp.next;` = *as long as the next element to the one we're currently observing is not `null`, let's make the one we're currently observing that next node of this node*.

Answer (score 0):

The `Node` class is the representation of a node in a linked list. Each `Node` has its own `data` and a pointer/reference to the next `Node`, which is stored in the `next` member of the `Node` class.

Now answering your question about traversal. We start the traversal from the head of the linked list - `Node temp = head;`. We now use a while loop to traverse the linked list and stop only when we reach the last `Node` in the linked list. The last node will have the `next` reference as `null`, hence the condition `while(temp.next != null)`. Inside the loop, you are hopping to the next node and the loop will stop when you reach the last node. You then set the new `Node` as the next node of the last node in order to fulfill the data insertion function.

Comment: sort of figure it out, correct me if im wrong. the while loop is the key to keep the node pass on and on, when temp.next is not null, temp.next will pass it reference to temp and tell it where the next position is, because of the while loop, the node will go on and on until it finally find out a temp.next which is a null value, and jump out of the while loop and assign the node at the last node？